# node-watch does not watch directory when the app runs via forever.js

Tags: node.js

I have an app that monitors a directory for file changes and the send a notification via socket.io to the user. and this works great when i run `node app.js` but when i start it with `forever start /dir/to/app.js` the application runs and you can connect to it from the browser but no notification from node-watch are received. No errors that im aware of show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `"watch": true` in your forever config file.

That will cause your whole app to restart whenever there is a file change, which will cause `node-watch` to be restarted with the current state of the filesystem, so `node-watch` will never be able to detect a change.

If your socket pool is stored outside the node process' memory (EG. using the `socket.io-redis` adapater), your browser client will automatically reconnect after the app restarts without any issues.

Comment: ok im going to test that now thank you. ill let you know what i find

Comment: Just additional info for those that read this later. @paulpro i think this is in-conjunction with your answer, But the difference with what worked and what didn't worked was with how i started the forever start script. `forever start /path/to/app.js` does not allow Node-Watch to work while `cd path/to/; forever start app.js` works as intended. Though i am not sure why it works that why. Thanks again